# Remove users with no created nodes D7

Tags: rules, users

I have a site setup where users create a node as soon as they login from the activation link sent via email. I've recently been getting tons of people signing up but not creating any nodes because the emails they register with are obviously fake so I would like to remove all the users with the role listing user that hasn't created a node withing a day of registration.

I need help doing this with Rules if at all possible please. If you have any other methods that doesn't involve complex php that would help as well.

Thanks

Comment: Also consider using some spam limiters like [BOTCHA](https://www.drupal.org/project/botcha)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a View that shows the users who haven't authored any nodes, and then use VBO https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations  to delete those users.

Answer (score -1):

You can hook to the cron that runs daily that check and delete those users.